# Locate function call in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm new to laravel but not php. I was tasked to optimized some backend query and needed some help on locating where the model function "getPackagesSoldAttribute" is being called here. I don't see in the controller that this function is being called like ProEvent::getPackagesSoldAttribute for example.

So my view is showing the return of the function. Any idea how did laravel called this function? I also did check PHP DebugBar and I saw the query the getPackagesSoldAttribute function used.

I also created a script that would locate the string "getPackagesSoldAttribute" but could only find one and that is in the model.

```
Route::get('{organiser_id}/pro_events/{filter?}', [
            'as'   => 'showOrganiserProEvents',
            'uses' => 'OrganiserProEventsController@showOrganiserProEvents',
        ]);
```

This is the controller function called by route.

```
public function showOrganiserProEvents(Request $request, $organiser_id, $filter = null, $listView = null)
    {
        $add_on_check       = \App\Models\OrganisationAddon::where('org_id', $organiser_id)->first();
        $edit_create_enable = "";
        $delete_enable      = "";

        if( !empty($add_on_check) ){
            $add_ons            = json_decode($add_on_check->add_ons);
            $edit_create_enable = !empty($add_ons->enable_create_edit_event)?"1":"";
            $delete_enable      = !empty($add_ons->enable_delete_event)?"1":"";
        }

        $organiser = Organiser::find($organiser_id);

        $allowed_sorts = ['created_at', 'event_date', 'title'];

        $searchQuery = $request->get('q');
        $sort_by = (in_array($request->get('sort_by'), $allowed_sorts) ? $request->get('sort_by') : 'event_date');
        $eventListView =  empty($request->get('view_list_by')) ? 'grid' : $request->get('view_list_by');

        if($listView){
            $eventListView = $listView;
        }

        if($filter == null){
            $filter = "live";
        }

        if( $searchQuery ){

            $the_event = ProEvent::where('title', 'like', '%' . $searchQuery . '%');

            if($sort_by == 'event_date'){
                $the_event->orderBy($sort_by, 'asc');
            } else {
                $the_event->orderBy($sort_by, 'desc');
            }

            $the_event->where('organiser_id', '=', $organiser_id);

            if( $filter == "templates"){
                $the_event->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('event_status', 'template');
                    $query->orWhere('is_master', 1);
                });
            }else if( $filter == "live" ){
                $the_event->where('event_status', "live");
            }else if( $filter == "past" ){
                $the_event->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('event_status', 'past');
                    $query->orWhere('event_date', '<', Carbon::now());
                });
            }else if( $filter == "testing" ){
                $the_event->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('event_status', 'testing');
                    $query->orWhere('event_status', 'pos_testing');
                });
            }else if( $filter == "abandoned" ){
                $the_event->where('event_status', "abandoned");
            }

            $events = $the_event->get();

        }else{

            $the_event = ProEvent::where('organiser_id', '=', $organiser_id);

            if($sort_by == 'event_date'){
                $the_event->orderBy($sort_by, 'asc');
            } else {
                $the_event->orderBy($sort_by, 'desc');
            }

            if( $filter == "templates"){
                $the_event->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('event_status', 'template');
                    $query->orWhere('is_master', 1);
                });
            }else if( $filter == "live" ){
                $the_event->where('event_status', "live");
            }else if( $filter == "past" ){
                $the_event->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('event_status', 'past');
                    $query->orWhere('event_date', '<', Carbon::now());
                });
            }else if( $filter == "testing" ){
                $the_event->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('event_status', 'testing');
                    $query->orWhere('event_status', 'pos_testing');
                });
            }else if( $filter == "abandoned" ){
                $the_event->where('event_status', "abandoned");
            }

            $events = $the_event->get();

        }

        $data = [
            'event_types' => $organiser->pro_event_types,
            'events'    => $events,
            'organiser' => $organiser,
            'search'    => [
                'q'        => $searchQuery ? $searchQuery : '',
                'sort_by'  => $request->get('sort_by') ? $request->get('sort_by') : '',
                'showPast' => $request->get('past'),
            ],
            'edit_create_enable' => $edit_create_enable,
            'delete_enable'      => $delete_enable,
            'filter'             => $filter,
            'eventListView'      => $eventListView

        ];

        return view('ManageEmsPro.ProEvents', $data);
    }
```

This is the model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Str;
use URL;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use File;
use Image;
use Log;
use Storage;

class ProEvent extends MyBaseModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table   = 'pro_events';
    protected $appends = array('packages_sold', 'bundles_sold');

    /**
     * The validation rules.
     *
     * @var array $rules
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'information_link'     => ['regex:/^(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/'],
        'redirect_link_url'    => ['regex:/^(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/'],
        'web_sales_start_date' => ['required'],
        'sales_start_date'     => ['required'],
        'open_time'            => ['required'],
        'close_time'           => ['required'],
        'title'                => ['required'],
        'description'          => ['required'],
        'event_date'           => ['required'],
        'organiser_name'       => ['required_without:organiser_id'],
        'event_image'          => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:3000'],
        'custom_url'           => ['regex:/(^[\w\d_-]+$)/u'],
        'payment_percentage'   => ['numeric', 'between:0,99.99', 'min:1'],
        'event_logo'           => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:1000'],
        'organiser_event_logo' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:1000'],
    ];

    /**
     * The validation error messages.
     *
     * @var array $messages
     */
    protected $messages = [
        'title.required'                       => 'You must at least give a title for your event.',
        'organiser_name.required_without'      => 'Please create an organiser or select an existing organiser.',
        'event_image.mimes'                    => 'Please ensure you are uploading an image (JPG, PNG, JPEG)',
        'event_image.max'                      => 'Please ensure the image is not larger then 3MB',
        'custom_url.regex'                     => 'Allowed special characters are only "_" and "-"',
        'event_logo.mimes'                     => 'Please ensure you are uploading an image (JPG, PNG, JPEG)',
        'event_logo.max'                       => 'Please ensure the image is not larger then 1MB',
    ];

...

public function getPackagesSoldAttribute(){
        $valid_packages  = PackageInventoryMap::where("pro_event_id", $this->id)->pluck('package_id');
        $valid_orders    = ProOrders::whereNotIn("order_status_id", [2,4])->where("organiser_id", $this->organiser_id)->pluck('id');
        $pro_order_items = ProOrderItem::whereIn('pro_order_id', $valid_orders)
                                ->where("pro_event_id", $this->id)
                                ->whereIn('package_id', $valid_packages)
                                ->whereNull("bundle_ids")
                                ->sum('quantity');
        return (integer)$pro_order_items;
    }

...
```

This is part of the view.

```
<div class="row">
        @if($events->count())
            @if($eventListView == "grid")
                <div class="col-sm-12 grid-search">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="pull-right lh-2">
                            Search: <input class="form-control pull-right input-sm grid-filter">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                @foreach($events as $key => $event)
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 data-event-block" data-event-block="{{ $key+1 }}" style="display: {{ $key <= 9 ? 'block' : 'none' }}">
                        @include('ManageEmsPro.Partials.EventPanel')
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @elseif($eventListView == "table")
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @include('ManageEmsPro.Partials.EventTable')
                </div> 
            @endif
        @else
            @if($search['q'])
                @include('Shared.Partials.NoSearchResults')
            @else
                @include('ManageEmsPro.Partials.EventsBlankSlate')
            @endif
        @endif
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators). `getPackagesSoldAttribute` is an "Accessor" method. Basically, you wont see `getPackagesSoldAttribute` called directly, instead, when the code calls `$model->packages_sold`, in the background, laravel will actually call `$model->getPackagesSoldAttribute` dynamically and return its response as that value.

For example, if you wanted to debug or test this method, you might do something like:

```
$event = ProEvent::find($someId);
$packagesSold = $event->packages_sold; // this line will call the  `getPackagesSoldAttribute` and set `$packagesSold` to the value it returns.
```

Also of note:

The model here also defines an `appends` property with `packages_sold`

```
protected $appends = array('packages_sold', 'bundles_sold');
```

This will cause the `packages_sold` property to be automatically filled by the method in question any time the model is represented as an array or serialized. see also
[Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick reply, really appreciate. I'll check your advice and let you know what I'll find.

Comment: Just saw in the view calling this as <h4 class="nm">{{ $event->packages_sold == 0 ? "0" : $event->packages_sold }}</h4> Thanks again!

Comment: Also Id like to point out in case someone might have similar setup/scenarios. That {{ $event->packages_sold == 0 ? "0" : $event->packages_sold }} is bad idea because you are calling the method twice. {{ $event->packages_sold }} will do.